# Variance of total outcome after multiple trials

Tags: variance

I have a typical gambling game with 3 outcomes. So we have a random variable $X=\{0,2,19\}$. They're not necessarily equally likely, so they have a probability distribution.

It's easy enough to find the variance of a single play of the game, $V[X]$. But what if we get to play the game $N$ times, what is the variance of the total amount won after $N$ plays, with each play of the game independent of previous plays? Extending it one step further, what if $N$ is itself a random variable with a probability distribution? (An example distribution is $Prob(N) = (1-r)^{N-1}r$, ie, play until a certain chance event happens.)

If we play the game $N=2$ times, the outcomes from each turn are added together to produce the possible outcomes, $G=\{0,2,2,4,19,19,21,21,38\}$, with each outcome having an associated probability. We can calculate the variance of that without much trouble. But as $N$ grows larger, enumerating every possible outcome becomes unwieldy. In some sense, we're multiplying random variables, since we can easily find the total expected value, $E[G]=E[X]\cdot E[N]$. But the variance isn't so straightforward.

So we have 3 random variables:  $X$, $N$, and $G$.
And 5 easily derivable quantities: $E[X]$, $V[X]$, $E[N]$, $V[N]$ and $E[G]$

Is there a way to derive $V[G]$ from the above values?

The Long Story - Work I've done.
I do have a solution for $V[G]$, but it's the non-closed form found by carefully applying the formula for the variance. We get to play games until a chance independent event happens with probability, $r$. We have

$$ Prob(X=x_i) = \{p_0,p_1,p_2\} \\
 Prob(N=n) = (1-r)^{n-1}r $$
$$ V[G] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{a}\sum_{b} (1-r)^{n-1}r\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}p_0^ap_1^bp_2^c\cdot (a\cdot 0 + b\cdot 2 + c\cdot 19 - E[G])^2  \\
 \forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{N_0} : a+b+c=n $$

or alternatively, a form that you can directly write in computer code
$$ V[G] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{a=0}^n\sum_{b=0}^{n-a} (1-r)^{n-1}r\frac{n!}{a!b!(n-a-b)!}p_0^ap_1^bp_2^{n-a-b}\cdot (a\cdot 0 + b\cdot 2 + (n-a-b)\cdot 19 - E[G])^2 $$

Which gives a rather rich geometric interpretation to the problem. We can view the possible outcomes after playing $n$ games as a linear 
combination of the basis vectors $\{0,2,19\}$, with the coefficients for those basis vectors coming from points on the plane $a+b+c=n$, bounded
by the box $[n,n,n]$, with this plane moving by 1 along one axis as each turn is played.

The probabilities for these individual outcomes comes from multiplying the appropriate individual probabilities, $p_0^ap_1^bp_2^c$, by $\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}$, where $\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}$ are the numbers from the $n^{th}$ slice of Pascal's pyramid.

This factor from Pascal's pyramid is there to account for the fact that you can get to same total outcome via multiple routes. (eg, you could win 0 the first turn
and 19 the second, or 19 the first and 0 the second), which allows you to put tighter bounds on the nested sums. This ultimately makes it feasible to calculate a numerical
approximation of the problem, because the number of terms on each slice of the pyramid grow in an $n^2$ fashion rather than $3^n$ (in practice, you can run the sum up to a value of n=171 before double precision numbers fail). It also tells me there's some convolutions involved, but I can't figure out how to extract out the terms with n, in order to properly handle the infinite sum.

Comment: "But what if we get to play the game N times" Are they independent? i.e., the results from each game have no effect on others?

Comment: Yes, the results from one game to the next are independent. I'm specifically modelling the total amount won after playing a keno game, n times.

Comment: Your G is random vector? Var(G) is variance-covvariance matrix?

Comment: I was just using G as the set of total different outcomes. In my example above, G was after N=2, so you could get 21 by getting 2 your first turn and 19 your second, or 19 your first turn and 2 your second. Thus E[G] = E[X]*E[N]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $N$, let $X_0$ be the number of 0 appeared among $N$ plays, $X_1$ be the number of 2 appeared among $N$ plays, and $X_2$ be the number of 19 appeared among $N$ plays.

Then random vector $X=(X_0, X_1, X_2)$ follows multinomial distribution with $(N, p_0, p_1,p_2)$ as parameters. It has mean vector $N(p_0, p_1, p_2)$ and varaince covariance matrix
$$ Var(X) =N\left(\begin{matrix}p_0(1-p_0) & -p_0p_1 & -p_0p_2\\
                                           -p_0p_1 & p_1(1-p_1) & -p_1p_2\\ -p_0p_2 & p_1p_2& p_2(1-p_2)\end{matrix} \right) =N\Sigma$$

The money won in the game is $ Y = 0x_0 +2X_1 + 19X_2 = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 2 & 19\end{matrix} \right) \left(\begin{matrix}X_0&X_1&X_2
                                           \end{matrix} \right)'$

Then we have $E(Y|N) = N(2p_1 + 19p_2)$ and $Var(Y|N)= (0, 2, 19)N\Sigma \left(\begin{matrix}0&2&19\end{matrix} \right)'$

When $N$ is random and follows the distribution $\Pr(N=n) = (1-r)^{n-1}r$, we have $E(N)=\frac 1r$ and $Var(N)= \frac {1-r}{r^2}$, so

$$Var(Y) = E(Var(Y|N)) + Var(E(Y|N)) = (0, 2, 19)\Sigma \left(\begin{matrix}0&2&19\end{matrix} \right)'E(N) + (2p_1 +19p_2)^2Var(N) = \frac 1r(0, 2, 19)\Sigma \left(\begin{matrix}0&2&19\end{matrix} \right)'+(2p_1+19p_2)^2\frac{1-r}{r^2}$$

Comment: I appreciate the response but I'm a little confused on notation. What exactly does $\sum_{j=1}^NX_j$ mean? What would $X_2$ or $X_3$ be?... I do have multinomial coefficients in my summation approach (the $\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}p_0^ap_1^bp_2^c$ terms), and it's almost like I can see part of my summation equation in there, but I still can't quite see how to avoid enumerating every outcome at each n.

Comment: I added details in Answer. Is it clear? $\sum_{j=1}^NX_j$ is the money you win after N games.

Comment: Oh wow... This is a bit embarrassing, I'm more confused now. I don't know where the (1-p)'s come from nor the other minus signs.. There must be an entire statistics topic here with which I'm unfamiliar.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution, right side, row with "variance" in the table.

Comment: The answer is based on the following: Play a game, win \$0 with prob. $p_0$, win \$2 with prob. $p_1$, and win \$19 with $p_2$. The game will play one by one until a event happens with probability $\Pr(N=n) = (1-r)^{n-1}r$. I assume you want the variance of total money you win when the game finished. If it is what you want, the answer is useless.

Comment: Yes, I want the variance of total money won after playing the game until you get the terminating event, which is independent and occurs with probability r. Meaning, on average, you'll play 1/r times until the game is terminated. If you played N times, your minimum win would be 0 with probability of $p_0^N$ and maximum win would be N*19 with a probability of $p_2^N$. The average win would be $E[G] = E[X]*E[N]$, where G is total money won. I may be a bit nonstandard with my notation, corrections are welcome. So is your answer what I'm looking for?

Comment: Then I am sure you can use my answer. By utilizing two formula (which I used) the thing becomes simple. 1) Variance of sum of independent random variables is the sum of the variance of each random variable. 2) $Var(Y) = E(Var(Y|N)) + Var(E(Y|N))$. In addition, need to know multinomial distribution.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct. Although it'll take me a minute to fully understand your answer, I think you've left me enough stepping stones to eventually get there. Thank you! (I think $p_1p_2$ in the matrix should have a minus in front of it, according to the wikipedia page, only the diagonal is non-negative)